# What is the performance impact of number of documents on the index build complexity?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb; is the increase of documents number in a collection, with five index, impact the build complexity of index and therefore the performance of insert operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; MongoDB uses a B-tree data structure to build the index. On the other hand, binary tree read, insert, or update operations have a complexity of O(log n), where n is the number of elements. So, yes increase in the Number of Documents in a collection, with multiple indexes, impact the performance of insert operation.